# The problem with fundamental theorem of calculus - part 2

Tags: calculus

Evaluation theorem i.e. the fundamental theorem of calculus part 2, that
" **if F is any antiderivative of f , then F(x) = G(x) + C for some constant C for a < x < b(by cor. 2 of Mean Value Theorem). Since both F and G are continuous on [a, b], we see that F(x) = G(x) + C also holds when x = a and  x= b by taking one sided limits(as x->a+ and x-> b-).**

My confusions are:

1) why is x taking to be in (a, b) and not [a, b]
2) why do we take one sided limits for seeing that F(x) = G(x) + C holds when both the functions are continuous? Couldn't we just plug in a and b themselves?

Comment: The first part doesn't seem to make much sense: "$\;F(x)=F(x)+C\;$ ..." What you probably meant is that if $\;F,G\;$ are both primitives of $\;f\;$ , then $\;F(x)=G(x)+C\;$ ...

Comment: There is no need to deal with open and closed intervals separately. Mean Value theorem ensures that the result holds in closed interval $[a, b] $.

Comment: @DonAntonio, it was a typo, sorry

Comment: @ParamanandSingh, then, could you explain, then, why the limits are taken?

Comment: In short they are taken unnecessarily. Perhaps your textbook author assumes that endpoint need special treatment because the functions may not differentiable at end points. The reality is that mean value theorem does not need differentiability at end points, but the conclusion is about endpoints also. While reading usual calculus textbooks be prepared to accept that they may contain such issues. Most such book authors don't really know the finer details.